# deeplinking is not working with https and https in react native IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, url-scheme

I'm adding the url scheme in the xcode perfectly, All other schemes are working perfectly except the http and https. Moreover, it is working on android with both http and https.

Would you help me in getting this issue solved.

[This is my Url scheme that i'm trying to use but unable to open the app in IOS using this scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NO2Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can not capture http/https schemes. Must use apple-app-site-associations
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

Comment: to capture https scheme, in android, we should also use app link instead of usual deeplink?

Comment: @Kakaranara Yes in Android you should use App Links to capture an https scheme.  Instead of apple-app-site-associations you need to use assetlinks.json. Debug testing you need the Android Studio generated sha256_cert_fingerprint Android Studio > App Links Assistant  > Associate Website > Generate Digital Asset Links File. Note that Build Variants must be set to debug. Production (Play store) requires Play Store generated sha256_cert_fingerprint Google Play Console > Release > Setup > App Integrity as app is signed by Google Play not key store.  Please post a link to your question for more info